# How do I programmatically play the Android NFC notification sound?

Tags: android, audio, nfc

I have an app (NFC Sniffer) which allows users to read NFC tags. When a user attempts to read a tag, 1 of 3 things happens:

1. Nothing, the tag was not brought close enough
2. Detected NFC, but fails to read card, in which case a notification tone is played.
3. Reads tag, in which case a different notification sound is played.

Lots of new users are confused about these notification sounds. I want my program to have a help screen, with buttons to play these two sounds.

But how do I locate and play these two notifications from my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get these sounds from the sources of the AOSP project and include them in your own app. The sounds are part of the NFC system service app:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/res/raw/

Btw. starting with Android 4.4, you can disable the sounds while your activity is in the foreground by using the [reader mode API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode%28android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) with the flag [`NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS).

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed. I then used a SoundPool to play these sounds.

Comment: Sadly I later encounter phones that used different sounds. So the sounds may vary with the hardware.

Comment: Big thanks for the info on the existing sounds. Interesting, that my current reading, when receiving "Tag was lost" error, does not play the above mentioned "error" sound.

At least now with reader API I can play it manually.